# i want to pass a value in an input from another value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

Hello thats what i have already tried
https://jsfiddle.net/arispapapro/1qbjd36c/2/

```
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="no301" class="form-control" id="no301" placeholder="">
    <input type="text" name="no307" class="form-control" id="no307" placeholder="">
    </form>

    document.getElementById("no307").value = $('no301').val();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this using pure Javascript.

```
var no307 = document.getElementById("no307");
var no301 = document.getElementById("no301");



no307.onchange = function(){
  no301.value = no307.value;
}

no301.onchange = function(){
  no307.value = no301.value;
}
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8tyuebj5/1/)

If you are using jquery then you can do like this.

```
$("#no301").on('change',function(){

    $("#no307").val( $(this).val() ); 

})


$("#no307").on('change',function(){

    $("#no301").val( $(this).val() ); 

})
```